# Hide element based on the route path in Angular 5,6

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'm managing an Angular project now and I faced a curious thing while trying to improve the system. Some elements should not be displayed on certain urls.

**Is there any way to hide the element based on the url in Angular 5 or 6?**

I want to know about the best experience to achieve this.

For example, domain.com/**home**, domain.com/**package**, etc.

Comment: elements on the page based on something like window.location.path?

Comment: @AustinTFrench, route in angular I mean, so for example, I want to hide the element when the route is /home and /package etc.

Answer (score 2):

In angular we generally create less and less directive since component feet 90% of the case. But here is the typical case where you need to create one :).

1 - Create a Directive en Inject  the router:

```
 import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

 @Input() url : string;

 constructore(private router: Router){
   router.events.subscribe( (event) => {
     // I think you can see the route change here :)
   });
 }
```

From here you will be able to know on which route you are.

2 - Now hide or not ?

You can also inject templateRef and the containerRef to play with the DOM.

```
 import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

 constructore(private route: Router,
              private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef){
 }
```

3 - To finish :

```
    if (this.url // On a good URL show the content) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
```

4 - You just have to add this directive on a element you want to manage